# JSON DataAdapter using API causing slow report generation

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am having my API where I am sending a request from POSTMAN and it takes less than a second to respond. But, when I use the same API in JasperReport using JSON DataAdapter, it takes about 7 to 15 seconds to respond and generate the report. Here is a snapshot is taken after uploading the report to the server using Mozilla.
[image: browser]
Here is the same report on the POSTMAN
[image: postman]
It is not fetching anything from the API but just the login key. Here is a snapshot from the JasperStudio
[image: jasper studio]

Here is my **jrxml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.10.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.10.0-unknown  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_A4" language="javascript" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="200" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8fe94703-075f-4ae1-affc-bff8d7a8a4b8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="POST_REQUEST_TO_GET_TOKEN"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://server_address:port/jasperserver/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="user"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/Sub_Reports/test_A4"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/Sub_Reports/test_A4_files/main_jrxml"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="POST_REQUEST_TO_GET_TOKEN.xml"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="59" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="59" uuid="691c8e97-8888-4786-9350-62d5f187820b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="19" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This is a drill down sample report"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="75" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="50" uuid="4aba0c46-cda3-4611-97a2-1f446bd4f85b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[It sends a POST request to an API and receives a token to put it into another POST request which will bring back the data from the API]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="45" width="555" height="30" uuid="447eee49-5f57-4280-8f47-f5a5a8ff6503"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This is in sub-reprots directory"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I am unable to get the cause of many delays. Would anyone please help me figure this out? Thanks a lot.
I am using JasperSoft Studio 6.10 and JasperServer Version 7.

Comment: Why is it voted for closed? Anyone would please tell me?