# Connecting Jasper Report with Rest API on Jasper Server

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I have created a report where my Data Source is the REST API. The API works in the following way:

1. User sends username and password
2. A token is generated and sent back as a response
3. User uses this token in the next requests and it expires after a defined time.

I am having a problem with my report. I have used the API in my report but it needs to log in each time and gets a token to access the data which takes up to 8-15 seconds to build and display the report. That is causing an extra delay in report generation which is irritating and is unacceptable. Is there any way I could overcome logging in each time while generating a report?
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65201117/json-dataadapter-using-api-causing-slow-report-generation) explains my time taken to generate the report on differnt platforms and also contains the code to generate the report.
Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you manage to make jasper api return a token to you?

Comment: @Gustavo I created two different data adapters for this. 1st one takes the API token and places it in 2nd adapter